# Getting the value of ajax populated combo box on document.ready

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have 3 combox box on a page and i want all to populate the value according to the value of last one. 
like combobox 2 dependent on combobox1 value , and combobox 3 depend on combobox 2 value.
page is running fine on upto combobox 2 but its not getting the getting the value of combobox2 when page is ready which is ajax populed on page load

i am using this code

```
var val=$('#cat option:selected').text();
    var sub=$('#sub option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({

        url:'ajaxrequest/get.flvr.php',
        type:'post',
        data:'name='+val+'&sub='+sub,
        success:function(msg){
            alert(msg)
            //$('#flavour').empty();
            //$('#flavour').append(msg);
        }
    })
```

alert showing empty box.. if alerts shows fine then i will append the value in 3rd one
can anybody help me on this. thanks

Comment: and this is all wrapped in an document ready func?

Comment: and this is all wrapped in an document ready func? if so what you need to do is wrapp it in a named function say 'function init()' and call this func in your document ready func and then call it again in your ajax success func because the html values don't exist in combo 2 when the document is initialized (document ready) but by calling init again in the success func init will pick up the new additions to the dom